# How to make the search form find the match from the category and then paste the value in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a quick search form with Bootstrap 2.3.2. I'm using a dropdown menu on the lhs of the input field and then a submit button on the rhs like this:

[image]

I want the user to select the category from the list first and then when he/she type the keywords and submit. The search would be able to filter the label from the list and then paste the match ones in the div below.

The JS I am using is:

```
$(function () {
var data = [...];

function result(message) {
    $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#result");
    $("#result").scrollTop(0);
}

$("#index-search").submit(function () {
    if ($(".dropdown-menu").text() === data.val(ui.item.id) {
        return;
    });
});
```

But I could not figure out how to filter the result with the label selected.

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks

The JsFiddle link is here: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wx688/4/)

Comment: I can't see any relation between the *data* and the *category* in the fiddle.

Comment: Your JSfiddle had a jqeury error, just fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/wx688/3/ I'll keep looking.

Comment: @celerno still it has the error, it's in the `if` switch. But the fiddle actually doesn't makes sense though.

Comment: @code-jaff I am sorry, for the category I mean the "label" inside "data", sorry for the confusion. And I know the if statement does not make sense now, because I could not find the way to pick out the text from the dropdown menu and compare to the label inside the data

Comment: @celerno thanks for help. I just wondering how to fliter the text from the dropdown menu with the label inside data

Comment: a question, the array "data" was intended to be the data source of the dropdown?

Comment: @celerno no, the data is the original source, dropdown is used to select the category from the data, and this is my update, maybe could clear some confusion http://jsfiddle.net/wx688/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for a solution like this,

**JS**

```
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function () {
    $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [{
        value: "Full A",
        id: "10",
        label: "Client"
    }, {
        value: "A La",
        id: "2",
        label: "ID"
    }, {
        value: "B RDE",
        id: "3",
        label: "Description Needed"
    }, {
        value: "M Smoth",
        id: "45",
        label: "Room"
    }, {
        value: "Steven C",
        id: "6",
        label: "Kitchen"
    }, {
        value: "Ada B",
        id: "78",
        label: "Bathroom"
    }];

    function result(message) {
        $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#result");
        $("#result").scrollTop(0);
    }

    $("#index-search").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filterBy = $(".dropdown-toggle").text().toLowerCase();
        var val = data.filter(function(e){
            return e[filterBy].toLowerCase() == $("#appendedPrependedDropdownButtons").val().toLowerCase();

        });
        console.log(val);
        result(val.length ?
                   "Selected: " + val[0].value + " aka " + val[0].id:
          "Nothing selected, input was " + $("#appendedPrependedDropdownButtons").val() );
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wx688/5/)

Comment: Hi thanks its excellent, but right now if two or more values in the array have the same value, and I want to put all of them in the div, how to fix it? like this http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/wx688/6/, I want the label contains "bathroom", but it only append the first one.